# Swoole php module : undefined symbol: spl_ce_Countable issue

Tags: php, swoole

I'm trying to install swoole on my machine

first :

```
pecl install swoole
```

Then i need a php module

```
cd swoole         
phpize             
./configure        
make               
sudo make install
```

The script create a swoole.so in my folder, so i add it in my php.ini :

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/swoole.so
```

When i try php -v, i'v got:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/swoole.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20151012/swoole.so (/usr/lib/php/20151012/swoole.so: **undefined symbol: spl_ce_Countable**), /usr/lib/php/20170718//usr/lib/php/20151012/swoole.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718//usr/lib/php/20151012/swoole.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 08:07:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans

What is this error : undefined symbol: spl_ce_Countable ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have PHP at `/usr/lib/php/20170718`  but you build Swoole at `/usr/lib/php/20151012`. Do you have several PHP versions installed and you're using the wrong one?

Comment: Yes i have /usr/lib/php/20170718 folder and 5.6, 7.0, 7.2 installed versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had several php versions installed on my machine. But version 7.2 did not have a php-config file.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev
```

this solved my problem

Thanks to @Álvaro González

Answer (score 3):

Most of the times, such error is thrown when you try to load an extension which depends upon other extensions which are either not loaded yet or not enabled. Therefore, it is recommended to load it via `phpenmod`. Some Linux distributions like Debian or Ubuntu use the PHP `mods-available` to load PHP extensions.

You can either create a file manually for extension name like `openswoole.ini` in following directory `/etc/php/<PHP_VERSION>/mods-available` with following data

```
; Configuration for Open Swoole
; priority=30
extension=openswoole
```

Or you can run below commands, remember to change `<PHP_VERSION>` to your php version

```
sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/php/<PHP_VERSION>/mods-available/openswoole.ini << EOF
; Configuration for Open Swoole
; priority=30
extension=openswoole
EOF"


sudo phpenmod -s cli openswoole


php -m | grep openswoole
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, so please read carefully.

If php modules are loaded from mods-available folder, don't add `extension=swoole.so` manually to php.ini, instead of that you have to add a `swoole.ini` file to php mods-available folder.

```
;configuration for php common module
;priority=20
extension=swoole.so
```

and enable it with `sudo phpenmod swoole`

What happens is if you add extension=swoole.so manually to php.ini, it connects before all the required extensions.
For instance, if you added --enable-sockets and so to swoole installation and the swoole extension loads before sockets extension, it will fail, so after I removed extension=swoole.so from php.ini, added swoole.ini file to php mods-available folder and enabled it with sudo phpenmod swoole swoole is working properly.

Copied from: https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src/issues/3952#issuecomment-782765934